# Como exportar um arquivo powerpoint para HTML?

Tags: html, css, html5, powerpoint

Tenho um arquivo **Power Point** que é interativo, ou seja, alguns botões enviam o usuário para outro slide, e continua sendo interativo a cada slide.
Preciso gerar um `HTML` para inserir em uma página web de modo que essa interatividade não se perca. Se tornando um tipo de carrossel.

O `HTML` hoje já existe e foi gerado a partir de um `PPT`, porém, por outro desenvolvedor, e eu preciso dar manutenção. Tenho o arquivo `PPT` original e já fiz as alterações que preciso, apenas não consigo gerar o `HTML` novamente.

Tentei usar algumas ferramentas online porém elas geram o `HTML` parecido com `PDF`. Não é interativo, não parece um carrossel e sim um arquivo vertical.

Alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File > Save As Page Web.

Ai ele ira salvar em pagina WEB. da uma olhada, ja tem uma pergunta dessa no Stackoverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274218/how-to-convert-from-powerpoint-to-html-css-foss

Comment: Ao gerar a página ela fica como um PDF, e não interativa. O meu powerpoint tem vários hiperlinks, enviando o usuário de página a página. Gostaria que o HTML fica-se da mesma forma.